# Need Excel CONCATENATE formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

I need help with a CONCATENATE formula that has quotes. I need it to add this to the cell.

```
appcmd set site /site.name:"YOURWEBSITE.COM" /-bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:XYZXYZ']
```

However I need `XYZXYZ` to be the value found in cell A2. How can I do this?

Comment: Just surround each single quote, with double quotes, Like "'"&"*:"&"443:"&A2&"'"

Comment: Refer to [Excel concatenation quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317359/excel-concatenation-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

To get a quote in the concatenate you could use Char(34) or use the name manger to hold the quote. As an example

- =+CONCATENATE("Start ",**Quote**,"Special Text",**Quote**," Finish")

results in
 Start "Special Text" Finish

To do this, go into the name manager (located on the formula tab on the ribbon) and give the Char(34) a name such as Quote.

[image]

without the name manager it is

- - =+CONCATENATE("Start ",**Char(34)**,"Special Text",**Char(34)**," Finish")

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula in the below image is what you want?

Cell A3 has the results of the concatenation.

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that most of the string, until the :, is in cell A1, this will work.

```
=TRIM(A1) & A2 & "']"
```

The trim is there in case there are extra spaces at the end.